# I sometimes get errors and sometimes I don't?

Tags: java, function, class, exception, random

I'm making a bingo programme.
I currently just want to make the 2D array representing the numbers on the bingo card.
Column 1 can only contain 1-15
Column 2 16-30
Column 3 31-45 etc....

This is my code so far and sometimes it throws an exception but sometimes it doesn't which is weird.

```
private int[][] bingoCard = new int [5][5];
public BingoCard()
{
    int [][]bingoCardInit  = new int [5][5];
    bingoCard = bingoCardInit;
}

public void fillInCard()
{
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[16];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) 
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<5; rowIndex++)
    {
        bingoCard[0][rowIndex] = arr[rowIndex];
        System.out.println(bingoCard[0][rowIndex]);
    }

    Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[16];
    for (int i = 16; i <= 30; i++) 
    {
        arr1 [arrayIndex]= i;
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr1));
    arrayIndex = 0;
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<5; rowIndex++)
    {
        bingoCard[1][arrayIndex] = arr1[rowIndex];
        System.out.println(bingoCard[1][arrayIndex]);
        arrayIndex++;
    }

    arrayIndex = 0;
    Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[16];
    for (int i = 31; i <= 45; i++) 
    {
        arr2 [arrayIndex]= i;
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr2));
    arrayIndex = 0;
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<5; rowIndex++)
    {
        bingoCard[2][arrayIndex] = arr2[rowIndex];
        System.out.println(bingoCard[2][arrayIndex]);
        arrayIndex++;
    }

    arrayIndex = 0;
    Integer[] arr3 = new Integer[16];
    for (int i = 46; i <= 60; i++) 
    {
        arr3 [arrayIndex]= i;
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr3));
    arrayIndex = 0;
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<5; rowIndex++)
    {
        bingoCard[3][arrayIndex] = arr3[rowIndex];
        System.out.println(bingoCard[3][arrayIndex]);
        arrayIndex++;
    }

}
```

I'm just wondering why it sometimes throws an exception.

Comment: can you post up your stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at BingoCard.fillInCard(BingoCard.java:37)
 at BingoCard.main(BingoCard.java:78)

but sometimes it changes to Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at BingoCard.fillInCard(BingoCard.java:23)
 at BingoCard.main(BingoCard.java:78)

and different numbers for some reason

Comment: can you point to those lines in your code?

Comment: With nullpointer problems, its just a case of stepping through and finding what is null, why, and where you need to make sure it sets up or doesnt get accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably why:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[16];
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) 
{
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

In your loop you initialize all the elements of the array except for the first element. Because of this the value of `arr[0]` is null.

Later on, you shuffle the elements in your `Integer` array and attempt to assign the first five values to your `int[][]` array...

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<5; rowIndex++)
{
    bingoCard[0][rowIndex] = arr[rowIndex];
```

In some cases, due to the the `Integer` array being shuffled, the null element will be one of the first five elements. Since you're attempting to assign an `Integer` to an `int`, unboxing will occur through the process of using the `intValue` method; and in the case of the null element, the NullPointerException is thrown.

A simple solution would be to use `arrayIndex` like you did in your other loops and to decrease the size of your arrays to 15 to avoid having elements that are null in them.

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[15];
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) 
{
    arr[arrayIndex++] = i;
}
```